# Rotate an SKShapeNode around an arbitrary point

Tags: swift, rotation, skshapenode

Is there a way to rotate an SKShapeNode, specifically a rectangle, around some arbitrary point?

I declared my SKShapeNode at the beginning of my gameScene class

```
var bladeTouch = SKShapeNode()
```

and set its path to form a rectangle

```
bladeTouch.path = CGPathCreateWithRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 198), nil)
```

However "bladeTouch" only manages to rotate around its bottom left corner, while my intention is to have it rotate around a point on the middle of its bottom edge. How would I go about translating its path so that this is possible?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be simplest:

```
bladeTouch.path = CGPathCreateWithRect(CGRectMake(-30, 0, 60, 198), nil)
```

Comment: However I would like to change the rectangle's point of rotation, rather than simply move the rectangle on top of it. So basically I want to move the point not the shape.

Comment: You can either recreate the path when you want to move the center of rotation, or you can change the node's `position`. Nodes don't have a general transform like views do.